# Finding a pointer of a field in C# using reflection

Tags: c#, memory, reflection, jit

This question is for educational purposes only.
I am aware of how a native program is working. The compiler takes each primitive and gives it an address, then uses that address in the program. For structures, it simply stacks the address together (with some padding) - but basically, a structure doesn't really "exist".
The native program doesn't tell me which fields and variables it has. It only accesses different addresses - and if I look at the assembly, I can name each address if I want to, but the program won't give me that information. So assuming I am looking for a specific variable, I cannot do it without either examining the executing of the program, or it's assembly.
The .NET environment does tell me which variables it has and which fields it has. Using the `Assembly` class and `Reflection` namespace, I can load up a file and see which fields and classes it has.
Then, using a program which searches memory (whether its native or not) I can find the physical location of the field (by using it value, filtering out etc) - like `Cheat Engine` does. It will give me the actual address of the field in the memory, which is accessed by the assembly made by the `JIT`.
I know that the MSIL does not contain information about the desired location of a specific field. I am also almost certain that the `JIT` will never optimize the code by removing any class.

I know that the .NET debugger is an actual class in the program which allows `Visual Studio` to interact with the internal information of an application. When the debugger is missing, `Visual Studio` cannot read or write to fields, nor can it inspect the application in any way.

Is there any way, without the use of `Cheat Engine` or similar tools to **find the physical location of a field** in a static (or of a specific instance) class in a **running .NET process**? **Will the address be the same after each executing** (such as in native program) ? May it differ only on different platforms or machines? How does the `JIT` decide where to place a field?

If I was unclear, I wish to do it without access to the code of the program, i.e externally by another process (like a debugger, but for programs compiled under release).

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1453/Getting-unsafe-with-pointers-in-C

Comment: If I was unclear, I wish to do it without access to the code of the program, i.e externally by another process (like a debugger, but for programs compiled under release).

Comment: One gotcha is that, even if you know the relative field address, the absolute address can still change after GC, due to heap compaction and reference reassignment.  In order to be sure you have a valid pointer externally, you have to keep a trail of relative references back to a static root and then you have to watch for when the process is being hijacked and the references changed.  Because your process is external, you don't get the benefit of being updated when the .NET process is hijacked; you'll want to freeze the process (requiring very low-level access) while accessing its memory.

Comment: I can only really think of malicious uses for doing this.  If it's purely academic I'd think there are better ways to spend your time (perhaps on thinks with more potentially productive rather than harmful uses).

Comment: You could probably do something with the api that is exposed for debugging. The problem with any non static instances is that you have to find them. Now any stuff that is long lived in you application will be anchored somewhere statically, but all the transient stuff that is anchored only in the stack will be very difficult to find using reflection. Other than that you can use reflection and unsafe code to extract pointers to things - you can load the exe assembly and manually call the main method in a thread and then splunk through the code with reflection.

Comment: There are no guarentees that the GC will not move your stuff about on you though. I am not sure that this is a thing that you necessarily should do.... it seems like nothing you learn in the process is anything that you should ever apply to professional SW development.

Comment: I'm not academic, I'm fifteen. I simply like .NET. So basically, you guys say that it's very difficult and not really possible without a very sophisticated algorithm or such.

Comment: It's not something worth even thinking about unless you have a specific and very clear reason to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code inject Injector method in Paint.net and get MainForm fields.

### NInject.exe

```
public static int Injector(string parameter)
{
  try
  {
    var mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(form => form.GetType().FullName.EndsWith("MainForm"));

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendFormat("process: {0}\r\n\r\n", Application.ExecutablePath);
    builder.AppendFormat("type: {0}\r\n", mainForm.GetType().FullName);
    foreach (var field in mainForm.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
      builder.AppendFormat("field {0}: {1}\r\n", field.Name, field.GetValue(mainForm));
    }


    new Form()
    {
      Controls = 
      {
        new TextBox
        {
          Text = builder.ToString(),
          Multiline = true,
          Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }
      }
    }
    .ShowDialog();
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
  }
  return 0;      
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("PaintDotNet").FirstOrDefault();

  var processHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);

  var proxyPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "NInjector.dll");

  var pathBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(proxyPath);

  var remoteBuffer = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)pathBytes.Length, AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
  WriteProcessMemory(process.Handle, remoteBuffer, pathBytes, (uint)pathBytes.Length, IntPtr.Zero);


  var remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "LoadLibraryA") , remoteBuffer, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

  WaitForSingleObject(remoteThread, unchecked((uint)-1)); 

  CloseHandle(remoteThread);

}
```

### NInjector.dll (native)

```
#include "MSCorEE.h"
#pragma comment  (lib, "MSCorEE")

void StartTheDotNetRuntime()
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Started", L"proxy", 0);

    ICLRRuntimeHost *pClrHost = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CorBindToRuntimeEx(
        NULL, L"wks", 0, CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
        IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (PVOID*)&pClrHost);


    hr = pClrHost->Start();


    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    hr = pClrHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
        L"bla-bla\\NInject.exe",
        L"NInject.NInject_Program", L"Injector", L"MyParameter", &dwRet);



    hr = pClrHost->Stop();

    pClrHost->Release();
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    StartTheDotNetRuntime();
    break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:


        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

### Output:

```
process: C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\PaintDotNet.exe

type: PaintDotNet.Dialogs.MainForm
field appWorkspace: PaintDotNet.Controls.AppWorkspace
field defaultButton: System.Windows.Forms.Button, Text: 
field floaters: PaintDotNet.Dialogs.FloatingToolForm[]
field floaterOpacityTimer:  [System.Windows.Forms.Timer], Interval: 25
field deferredInitializationTimer: 
field components: System.ComponentModel.Container
field killAfterInit: False
field singleInstanceManager: PaintDotNet.SystemLayer.SingleInstanceManager
field queuedInstanceMessages: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
field processingOpen: False
field scrollPosition: {X=0,Y=0}
```

Comment: Ugh, can you please explain what is this and how it looks? from the code it seems that you are injecting a DLL, but I still fail to understand what is this.